# Docker: failed to start daemon: error while opening volume store metadata database: timeout

Tags: docker

When I try to run Docker:

```
sudo dockerd
```

I get this exception:

> failed to start daemon: error while opening volume store metadata
>   database: timeout

What I've tried but didn't help:

```
ps axf | grep docker | grep -v grep | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}' | sudo sh
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that I had two instances of Docker running. I solved that by killing them and then started docker again using `systemctl start docker`

Comment: Thanks, I used `sudo systemctl stop docker` and then ran `sudo dockerd` and it works for me.